# In the equation environment, how do I align an equation, AND an image AND the equation number?

Tags: graphics, equations, vertical-alignment

I am trying to add an image adjacent to an equation in the `equation` environment. When I use the code below, the equation and the image are aligned but the equation number jumps to the next line.  If I remove `\vcenter`, the equation and the equation number are aligned, but the image is shifted upward.

```
\begin{equation}\label{linspring}
  p = qx = \frac {q^2} {k} E.
  \vcenter{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Spring.eps}}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 14):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
     \begin{equation}\label{linspring}
       p = qx = \frac {q^2} {k} E.
            \qquad \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image} 
\end{equation}        
\end{document}
```

Adding the key `valign=c` from the `adjustbox` package can simply do the job.

Answer (score 10):

`\vcenter` is a low level command (a primitive, actually), that needs some care in using it.

You can do it without any low level command and any external package (besides `amsmath` that you should load anyway if you have math in your document): a one-line `gathered` environment will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{linspring}
p = qx = \frac{q^2}{k} E.
\qquad
\begin{gathered}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The number is not going to the next line but aligned to the baseline of the picture. To avoid this you need a `\hbox` while using `\vcenter`. Also it is better to use `width` instead of `scale` for `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
     \begin{equation}\label{linspring}
       p = qx = \frac {q^2} {k} E.
            \qquad \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked great.  And you are so quick!  I posed the question as we we started our initial decent and I fixed the issue with your suggestion before the internet was cut off.  Thanks so much again!